# IOS timer application

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have an application like timer in IOS. In the first screen i have button when i am click on it the timer is start and after some amount of time say 30 seconds i have run my application then i am stop my application (not in background) , i am terminating the application. I reopen my application after the timer shows 1 min, that is working fine but when i am changing the device system time then the timer shows different time.

```
NSTimeInterval oldTimeInterval = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:PunchInTimeWhenGoneBackgroundKEY];
        NSTimeInterval currentTimeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];


    //if(currentTimeInterval>oldTimeInterval)
    //{}

    WORKING_TIME = WORKING_TIME + (currentTimeInterval - oldTimeInterval) + 1;

    if(timerWorkTime!=nil)
    {
        [timerWorkTime invalidate];
        timerWorkTime = nil;
    }

    timerWorkTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(funCalculateWorkingTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)funCalculateWorkingTime
{

WORKING_TIME++;

workingHour   = (int) WORKING_TIME / 3600;
WorkingMin    = (int) WORKING_TIME / 60;
WorkingSecond = (int) WORKING_TIME % 60;

lblWorkingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d : %.2d : %.2d",workingHour,WorkingMin,WorkingSecond];

earnedMoney = ((float)WORKING_TIME * HOURLY_RATE)/3600.0;
lblTotalEarned.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f",earnedMoney];

   // NSLog(@"time : %@",lblWorkingTime.text);
}
```

Please do help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to correct this without using a server to provide the timer functionality.

Without the app being able to run in the background, any timer that you set to save and check even when the app is not running will rely on the local device's system time.  Any changes to the system time will mess that up.

My only thought would be to create a very simple server component where you could register a timer on the site, and then check with the server on startup to see what timers are available and how much time is left on them.

**Edit**: There is one option you could use, but it wouldn't be fool-proof.  You can use `CACurrentMediaTime()` to get a time that is relative to the boot time.  If the user changes time zones, or manually changes the system date, it would not be affected.  It would still be relative to the last system boot.  The down side is that it will throw off all your timers if the user restarts their phone.

Comment: My application is local and i am not using any web services so i can't do that if any other solution is there then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the system time for measurement. Store the time differences using UserDefaults or your own property list.

Comment: I have already used that you can also see that in my code also..but it  is not helping to full fill the issue.